# columnwise extended attributes in python for use in SAS

Tags: python, sas, metadata

I have a requirement to create extended attributes (XATTR) on columns in the python data frame. Reason: I need to import this dataset from python into SAS where SAS will recognize the XATTR on each column. Is this possible? Most of the articles I read were talking about to add XATTR at the file level. I need to access each column within the file and add a metadata to it called "label". Is this possible at all? Thank you.

Comment: xattr is a Python wrapper for extended filesystem attributes.  It has nothing to do with SAS dataset XATTR metadata.  Also in SAS a dataset LABEL or a variable LABEL is not an extended attribute.  Those are normal attributes that have been in SAS for 40+ years.

Comment: Thank you, Tom. I had misunderstood then (about the label). So where is the label stored in SAS? I don't see it in the main table with the original "data" columns. I am not very familiar with SAS. So please excuse my ignorance here. Also, any way we could create that "label" in python so SAS would somehow recognize it as "label"? I am guessing not? Thanks a ton!

Comment: Note: I use SAS Cloud, so I am limited by that (Cannot use SASPy)

Comment: How are you moving data between SAS and Python?  What Python package you using.  Check that package for how it supports variable labels.  In SAS to see metadata of a dataset use PROC CONTENTS.